# Pipeline Redis commands with Reactive Lettuce

Tags: redis, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I'm using `spring boot webflux` + `project reactor` + `lettuce` for connecting and querying Redis in a non blocking way.
I have configured the `ReactiveRedisTemplate` with `LettuceConnectionFactory`. The spring documentation states that the only way to use pipeline with `ReactiveRedisTemplate` is to use the `execute(<RedisCallback>)` method. In non-reactive `RedisTemplate`, I see that there is an `executePipelined(<RedisCallback>)` method which opens/closes a pipeline before executing the callback. But in case of `ReactiveRedisTemplate.execute` method, it uses a `LettuceReactiveRedisConnection` and neither `Spring ReactiveRedisConnection` nor `Lettuce` has no reference to pipeline.

So my question is, is it possible to pipleline your commands when using `Spring ReactiveRedisTemplate` + `ReactiveLettuceConnection`?

I also noticed that using `ReactiveRedisTemplate.execute` with a `RedisCallback` that has multiple Redis commands executes slower than just calling commands individually.

Sample code for pipleline with ReactiveRedisTemplate:

```
reactiveRedisTemplate.execute(connection -> keys.flatMap(key -> 
                                connection.hashCommands()
                                .hGetAll(ByteBuffer.wrap(key.getBytes()))))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                    .map(ByteUtils::getBytes)
                    .map(b -> {
                        try {
                        return mapper.readValue(b, Value.class);
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                        return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .collectList();
```

Code without pipeline:

```
keys.flatMap(key -> reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(key))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .cast(Value.class)
            .collectList();
```

Thanks!

Comment: i got the same problem, already googling around for 1 week have no results, do you have any solution?

Comment: @kriver. Did you find the answer to your question?. plz update with answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible using RedisReactiveTemplate or the reactive api of lettuce. Indeed when you construct your reactive chain some part of it will be lazily evaluated.

```java
getAsyncValue(a).flatMap(value -> doSomething(value)).subscribe()
```

For instance in this sample doSomething will be trigger only when getAsyncValue return a value.

Now if we take your RedisCallback sample and assume we have a flushAll method in the connection object. Where/when do you call it ?

```java
tpl.execute(connection -> {
                    Flux<Map.Entry<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer>> results = keys.flatMap(key ->
                            connection.hashCommands()
                                    .hGetAll(ByteBuffer.wrap(key.getBytes())));
                    connection.fluxAll();
                    return results;
                })
```

Like this nothe commands will be flushed to the server because no hashCommands would have been triggered.

Now let's look at all the signals callback we have:

- doOnNext
- doOnError
- doOnCancel
- doFirst
- doOnSubscribe
- doOnRequest
- doOnTerminate
- doAfterTerminate
- doFinally
- doOnComplete

doOnError or doOnCancel won't help us. But we could think about using doFinally, doOnTerminate, doAfterTerminate:

```java
tpl.execute(connection -> keys.flatMap(key -> connection.hashCommands()
                                        .hGetAll(ByteBuffer.wrap(key.getBytes())))
                                        .doFinally(s -> connection.flushAll()))
```

But htGetAll won't finish until command are flushed to the server so doFinnaly won't be call so we won't be able to flush....

The only workaround I can think of is to use directly async api of lettuce. There is a [sample in the documentation](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/index.html#pipelining.command-flushing) on how to do it.

Your code could looks like (not tested):

```java
// client is a RedisClient from lettuce

StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = client.connect();
RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> command = connection.async();
command.setAutoFlushCommands(false);
keys.map(command::hgetall)
                .collectList()
                .doOnNext(f -> command.flushCommands())
                .flatMapMany(f -> Flux.fromIterable(f).flatMap(Mono::fromCompletionStage))
```